# Desk Landline phone or VOIP phone for freelancing

Tags: working-from-home, scope-of-work, local-business

Due to COVID 19 I' am working from home for my regular job as well as freelancing. I want to have a separate number from my work cell phone and since I'll be working at a desk every day for 8-10 hours I need a desk phone.

The only thing that I need is a different number and line to keep my employment and freelancing separate. However, I've been hearing about VOIP and how it gives you extra features such as extra lines/extensions (which I doubt I even need).

So my question is....should I get a VOIP phone or just stick to a basic landline phone? I will be using the phone for answering calls from clients, cold/hot calling, lead generation with local businesses, and other basic calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use VOIP because our workers can be out and about doing personal things and still answer the call if they want to. As a single business member, this may be something for you to think about as well. This one way of keeping your personal contacts and business contacts separated if you need to save them. You do not have to do a lot of scrolling to find specific friend, or a specific customer through your contacts (if you have a lot of personal contacts on your phone).

I agree with Google Voice. We usually recommend that to our clients because they can give you an extra number for your phone and you do not have to pay a fee*.
*It is pay as you go and you only get charged for when you dial a number; you do not get charged if someone calls you.

https://voice.google.com/about

Answer (score 1):

I'd get a second cell... for business. Cell providers generally offer decent rates for a second line/device. Why even bother with a land line and another company in today's age. A second cell means you can take client calls if you aren't at your desk.

You could also use something a google number and forward it to your current cell. That way you know anything from *that* number is coming from the business line.

My personal opinion about VOIP is.. it's not fantastic. It works, but there are often things like echoes on the line - making calls difficult. There aren't any VOIP features that are really unique today.

---

All this being posted.. **I use one cell line for everything**... primarily it's used for business, but caller ID lets me know when a personal call is coming in. I mean, what's the difference other than how I answer? My friends and family know I answer it as a business line if I don't recognize the caller ID. The only downside is that I *must* answer it... so the telemarketers tend to get through still.

Comment: sounds far. I might go this route; however, I heard due to COVID-19 most jobs are thinking of keeping a few of their employees as permanent work-from-home employees; and making them buy VoIP phones everything connected remotely. But you still make a valid point.

Comment: You are aware that Skype is essentially a VOIP phone.

Comment: Skype is a VoIP phone, as long as you buy a DID.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Voice and have been for years. You can set so that it rings any phone line you have, set quiet hours, and set customized messages. It also texts you and emails voicemail transcripts if you choose. I have mine set so that it looks like my business is calling me - that way I know to answer it professionally. I was also able to pick my area code and number, thus giving me a local number when my cellphone was from out of the area. Because it's free, I don't know why you'd use anything else.

Comment: One example - it's not available everywhere (i.e. not in Canada) :)

Comment: @CanadianLuke Good point!